# Do 'dotnet build' and 'dotnet test' commands treat the -o/--output argument differently?

Tags: docker, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile for running unit tests inside a container.

I currently have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR "/src"

COPY ["ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj", "ProjectName/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ProjectName"
RUN dotnet build "ProjectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS test
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test", "ProjectName.csproj", "-c:Release", "-o:\"/app/build\"", "--no-build"]
```

The idea here is that it will build an image with binaries stored in `/app/build` and then execute the `dotnet test` command without rebuilding the project and knowing where the binaries are (because of the `-o:"/app/build"` parameter).

It builds fine, I can `-it bash` into the container and confirm that the assemblies are stored in the `/app/build` directory. However, once I try to execute the tests, it produces some weird error:

> Test run for /src/ProjectName/app/build/ProjectName.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
>
> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.2.0 (x64)
>
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> The argument /src/ProjectName/app/build/ProjectName.dll is invalid. Please use the /help option to check the list of valid arguments.

As I understand this, instead of treating the `-o:/app/build` as a directory in the root of the file system, it appends it to the current directory:

/src/ProjectName/**app/build**/ProjectName.dll

I can work around this and not specify the output directory at all, it is not critical for a unit testing container, however, I want to understand what the cause of the problem is.

Is it a .NET CLI bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Thank you.